# Media Wiki Image Upload not working

Tags: mediawiki

Our mediawiki installation on windows server 2012 causes this error message when trying to upload:

"Die Datei C:\Windows\Temp\php84DE.tmp konnte nicht unter mwstore://local-backend/local-public/d/dc/Far_logo_cont.gif gespeichert werden."

How to ensure that image upload is working?

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug

We will need a lot more info to be able to help you. As for the basics: Do the web server have writing rights to that directory?

Answer (score 1):

You should set read write and execute permissions for the Internet Guest Account (IUSR_MachineName of IIS < 7, or IUSR for IIS >= 7) on windows temp folder`%SystemRoot%\TEMP`